# How many rankings of indexing are there in Nominatim API

Tags: php, indexing, nominatim

We are currently installing Nominatim API and it is on Rank 30 (indexing), has been indexing for about 4 days now, does anyone know how many rankings there are to index?

Comment: depends what your importing -week + for the planet is not uncommon - http://gis.stackexchange.com/ is probably a better place to ask

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 30.

0 means the highest priority, 30 the lowest.

[Here is the full table of rank meaning](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Development_overview#Indexing.2Faddress_calculation).

[And here is really good explanation of meaning of those numbers next to ranks](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/30404/how-long-should-it-take-to-import-north-america-for-nominatim).

And from my experience ranks 26 (roads/streets) and 30 ("other") took the longest to load.

It's worth noting that if by any chance installation got interrupted at this point (when processing ranks), it can be safely resumed with:

```
./utils/setup.php --index --create-search-indices
```

And if the rank is 26 or higher, then also

```
--index-noanalyse
```

can be added.

Comment: I may be misleaded, but in my experience, the "--create-search-indices" after interrupted indexing returns an error (ERROR:  relation "idx_word_word_id" already exists).

So I used just "./utils/setup.php --index" to continue indexing from the last good Rank.